# Visual studio 2013 can't connect to SharePoint Online

Tags: visual-studio-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

I have an Office 365 account and I am trying to create a SharePoint App via Visual Studio 2013 Here are the steps:

1. Open VS 2013 and select `Office/SharePoint` > `App for SharePoint` (type
   the name) then click `OK`
2. I type in URL of the site (of course `https://`) and select `SharePoint-Hosted` option, then click `Finish`
3. I get the Office 365 authentication dialog box. I type in the username and password and it opens the SharePoint in the same rectangular dialog box and it stays there and nothing happens:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/ZgyW9.png]

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/rlUpJ.png]

If I click the close icon on the `Connect to SharePoint` dialog box that still shows my SharePoint online site, I get the following error:

[image]

If I click on OK I get the Connect to SharePoint dialog box again

[image]

Any idea? The strange thing I can do this on my other workstation.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you having similar issues connecting to other services, e.g. Word, OneDrive? What happens if you start from NAPA, create an app there and click on "edit in Visual Studio"?

Comment: problem is connect to SP pop up not save my credentials

Comment: I would still say it's a sign-in issue and though you didn't answer, I'm guessing it occurs with other services as well. Since you are able to log in on another computer, have you checked credential manager on the affected one? Does it work on another profile? If it does,you have your credentials saved somewhere, probably from Windows live id.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Works great on a different machine but the one I want as my dev box it won't connect. I'm using Win 8.1 Enterprise. Ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and just figured out it was related to my computer's clock. For whatever reason my clock time moved to 1 hour into the future (something related to daylight savings)? Once I corrected the clock time the login popup started working correctly again.

I figured this out thanks to Lync which actually told me that it couldn't log in due to the clock settings.

Answer (score 0):

make you pc time synchronized with internet time, and restart the windows time service. then authentication with online sharepoint should work fine